# ASP ajax gripview ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a CheckBox(ItemTemplate) in GridView inside UpdatePanel.
I would like to get the CheckBox value on code behind when the user click the btnAjax Button. How to do that?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="dgvUserGroup" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button ID="btnAjax" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnAjax_Click" />

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dgvUserGroup.DataSource = someDatatable;
        dgvUserGroup.DataBind();

}


protected void btnAjax_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            DataTable dtbTest = (DataTable)dgvUserGroup.DataSource;
            //how can i get the checkbox value here?
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {          
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many rows are there going to be in gridview with checkbox ? In case of multiple rows you want all selected checkboxes to be back or the only the first one or the last one or any random ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected void btnAjax_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in dgvUserGroup.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("chkRow");
            Boolean chkVal = chk.Checked;//Here You can get the value
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```